# Why does C++ allow variable length arrays that aren't dynamically allocated?

Tags: c++, standards-compliance, dynamic-arrays

I'm relatively new to C++, and from the beginning it's been drilled into me that you can't do something like

```
int x;
cin >> x;
int array[x];
```

Instead, you must use dynamic memory. However, I recently discovered that the above *will* compile (though I get a -pedantic warning saying it's forbidden by ISO C++). I know that it's obviously a bad idea to do it if it's not allowed by the standard, but I previously didn't even know this was possible.

My question is, why does g++ allow variable length arrays that aren't dynamically allocated if it's not allowed by the standard? Also, if it's possible for the compiler to do it, why *isn't* it in the standard?

Comment: Concerning your last question, why C++ doesn't support them, you might also consult this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c and the comp.lang.c++ thread linked in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Support for variable length arrays (VLAs) was added to the C language in C99.

It's likely that since support for them exists in gcc (to support C99), it was relatively straightforward to add support for them to g++.

That said, it's an implementation-specific language extension, and it's not a good idea to use implementation-specific extensions if you want your code to be portable.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was in the C standard. This explains it well, thanks!

Comment: @Maulrus: Keep in mind that in was in the C standard, this is completely separate from C++ standard.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's supported in C99.  I can't really speak to why it's not in the C++ standard.  However, it's not as useful as you might think because it easily leads (if you're not careful) to stack overflow (since it's typically based on [alloca](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/alloca.3.asp), itself non-standard).  Another mistake is to return a pointer to a dynamic array, which will immediately go out of scope.

Comment: So it'd be better to stick to dynamically allocated arrays in C99, even though it's in the standard?

Comment: @Maulrus never use VLAs with dimensions based on user input. However, the same is true for heap allocated arrays. You have to validate user input either way. So i don't see a problem specific to VLAs here. Here is my rough guideline: If the data-set is small, use a small statically sized array and an int saying how many elements are used. And if the data-set is large, use the heap. I don't see a use-case for VLAs, though.

Comment: It probably wasn't in the 1995 C++ standard because that preceded the C99 standardization of variable-length arrays.  It's probably not in the upcoming standard because `vector<>` offers similar functionality.

Comment: @Maulrus: Yes, because C99 has not near the widespread support C89 does.

Answer (score 3):

Lot's of compilers embrace and extend standards.  There are two basic reasons:

1. Nefarious compiler-writers probably think that making it harder to move away from their compiler helps increase longevity.
2. Benevolent compiler-writers probably think that giving you more options when they can at little to no cost to themselves is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

All of the reasons mentiond having to do with them being in C are correct, though there are limitations for the requirement.  You're example may demonstrate more flexible support than what is required in C (if you implemented that using scanf rather than cin, put it in a .c file, and used gcc).

This is almost just a implicit call to alloca (allocate auto) which just decreases the stack pointer (increasing the stack size) and copies the new stack pointer to another register which is used as a pointer to the allocated memory.

The difference is that constructors and destructors aren't going to be called on objects created with a alloca.